# Future "If" clauses and usage of present simple and present continous

Tags: conditional-constructions

what is the difference in the sentence: 
We won't be able to go out if it is raining.
We won't be able to go out if it rains.
Or are there interchangable?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

They might mean the same thing, but they could also mean something different:

- "We won't be able to go out if it *is raining*.
  This means that you can't go out *while* it's raining. The using of *raining* means that it's actually happening at the same time as you think of going out.
   Possibly: "We won't be able to go out if it is raining, *because we don't have any umbrellas*.
- "We won't be able to go out if *rains*.
  While this could mean that's it's currently raining (as the other sentence), it could also mean that it *has* rained at some point in the immediate past and it's the result of the rain that is concerning you.
  Possibly: "We won't be able to go out if it rains, *because, even if it's not currently raining, the ground will still be wet and we don't want to slip.*
  Alternatively: "We won't be able to go out if it *has rained.*

In short, the use of the *-ing* form of the verb refers to something that is actually happening. However, without the *-ing* it may or may not actually be happening at the time you are referring to. At best, it will have happened *sometime* between now and then.

---

Putting it a different way:

- ✔ "It will *be raining* tomorrow at 10:00 a.m."
- ✔ "It will *rain* tomorrow at 10:00 a.m."
- ✔ "It will *rain* tomorrow, but we don't know when."

However:

- ？ It will *be raining* tomorrow, but we don't know when.

While it's possible to say this, it's unusual.